# Which landmark paper first described the differentiation of T-cells?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, human-physiology, immune-system, history

T-cells are distinguished from B cells in part by their locus of differentiation/maturation (thymus). This is textbook knowledge, but I was wondering which particular person or people were responsible for making this discovery. I'd appreciate any links to their original papers/works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/369/6503/eaba2429?rss%253D1=#:%7E:text=T%20cells%20exiting%20the%20thymus,and%20secreted%20products%20or%20interleukins.) appears to be a history of the discovery of B/T differentiation and the role of the thymus. I believe that you should find a number of important references therein.

It describes specifically a series of publications in the 1950s and 1960s that may be relevant (section "Identification of T and B cells"), such as [this one by Gowans](https://www.nature.com/articles/196651a0).